# How can I solve this Null property on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to  put a delete button on each `li` using JavaScript and to make an event handler that runs when a button is clicked that removes the `li`. However when I try to add the handler, I get:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

I think this is because I am referencing a class that not exist before run the function `createbtn`. So How can I solve this?

The Code:

I set the variables, put querySelector to buttons because I testing how to do it:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.querySelectorAll ("li");
var buttons = document.querySelector (".btn-danger");
var li = document.createElement("li")
```

How I create the button:

```
function createbtn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
      btn.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger","btn-sm");
      list[i].appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

The function I try to run:

```
function liDel(){
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
 }

buttons.addEventListener("click", liDel);
```

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gj0wxyp/) to see all the code.

Comment: Try creating the button before using the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the null error is because;

- You have assigned the variable `buttons` to a node which doesn't exist yet. (Note that the button is created after the page has been loaded, which means `.btn-danger` hasn't yet been created at that time).
- According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) the `querySelector` method does the the ff:

  > The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, **null** is returned.

Based on the code you have in the fiddle, here is a guide to achieve the desired results.

First of all, get rid of the global `li` variable on line 6.
The reason is that if you create a new li from the input, it will render on the same line because it's still referencing the same element node (*I'm sure you've realized that*)

then in your `createListElement` function, do the ff

```
function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  btn.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger","btn-sm");
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    try{
      ul.removeChild(this.parentNode)
    }catch(err){
      alert(err.message)
    }
  })
  li.appendChild(btn)
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}
```

Then when you create the buttons, you have to attach the event listener function to it. So you do the ff in your `createbtn` function:

```
// To create a button 
function createbtn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
      btn.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger","btn-sm");
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if(!e) e = window.event;
        try{
          ul.removeChild(this.parentNode)
        }catch(err){
          alert(err.message)
        }
      })
      list[i].appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

anyways, there are more efficient ways to do this. But this is a quick workable model based on the code in your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Rather than querying and adding the event to the buttons object
try the chaining inside the document load.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector('.btn-danger').addEventListener('click', liDel);
};
```

The above code should work!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everybody, I got a solution after reading all your answers:
First I got rid the following:

```
var buttons = document.querySelector (".btn-danger");
var li = document.createElement("li")
```

Then create this function for remove the "li"
Using ***"this"*** you avoid the error for don't have a reference, because with that you don't care in what kind of element this is, you only now something is there and grab it for anything you need.

```
function liDel(){
    ul.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
```

and put this in createBtn for delete the existing "li" in the html:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', liDel);
```

then put this on createElement for do the same of the above, but for the new "li" creates with the DOM:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', liDel);
li.appendChild(btn);
```

And with that the problems was solved.

Thanks again and you can see how the page works on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gj0wxyp/50/)